# I want string divide space && replace first part of string with second part of string use python re.sub() method?

Tags: python, regex, string

String two-part fixed and separated by a space

```
import re
text="jahir islam"
print(re.sub(r' ',text))
```

**Input:** `jahir islam`
**Output:** `islam jahir`

Comment: What have you tried? This smells like homework.

Comment: please show your attempt to solve this..

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to do that. Just split the string on the space and reverse it and join it back;

```
input_str = "jahir islam"
output_str = " ".join(input_str.split(" ")[::-1])
```

Comment: Although the approach is sound, this code doesn't work.

Comment: `list.reverse()` reverses a list in place and returns `None`.

Comment: SHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH ;) finally fixed it by testing in interpreter.

Answer (score 2):

Using regex you can do this way if you know that you have only 2 words you need to swap

```
import re

text = 'jahir islam'
print re.sub(r'(.*) (.*)', r'\2 \1', text)
```

explanation:

```
re.sub(r'(.*) (.*)', r'\2 \1', text)
```

it groups the words and '\1' and '\2' are the representation of the groups you made, now you can place them any where as you want

for further query you can post a comment

Comment: reputation under 15 @Yugansh Marwah